# Convert 2D array to 3D numpy array

Tags: python, list, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a created a numpy array, each element of the array contains an array of the same shape (9,5). What I want is a 3D array.

I've tried using np.stack.

```
data = list(map(lambda x: getKmers(x, 9), data)) # getKmers creates a       
                                                 # list of list from a pandas dataframe
data1D = np.array(data)                          # shape (350,)
data2D = np.stack(data1D)
```

---

```
data1D:
array([list([      pdbID  AtomNo Type      Eta    Theta
0  1a9l.pdb     2.0    G  169.225  212.838
1  1a9l.pdb     3.0    G  168.439  206.785
2  1a9l.pdb     4.0    U  170.892  205.845
3  1a9l.pdb     5.0    G  164.726  225.982
4  1a9l.pdb     6.0    A  308.788  144.370
5  1a9l.pdb     7.0    C  185.211  209.363
6  1a9l.pdb     8.0    U  167.612  216.614
7  1a9l.pdb     9.0    C  168.741  219.239
8  1a9l.pdb    10.0    C  163.639  207.044,       pdbID  AtomNo Type          Eta    Theta
1  1a9l.pdb     3.0    G  168.439  206.785
2  1a9l.pdb     4.0    U  170.892  205.845
3  1a9l.pdb     5.0    G  164.726  225.982
4  1a9l.pdb     6.0    A  308.788  144.370
5  1a9l.pdb     7.0    C  185.211  209.363
6  1a9l.pdb     8.0    U  167.612  216.614
7  1a9l.pdb     9.0    C  168.741  219.239
8  1a9l.pdb    10.0    C  163.639  207.044
```

I get this error:
cannot copy sequence with size 9 to array axis with dimension 5

I want to create a 3D Matrix, where every subarray is in the new 3D dimension. I gues the new shape would be (9,5,350)

Comment: Please share a sample of the array and expected output

Comment: So you have an array of lists of pandas dataframes..??

Comment: As yatu says, the data structure seems off. To avoid the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), can you share more context about what you intend to do? Dataframes are designed with 2d data in mind (# of sample vs. property is the typical case), so it makes little sense to stack them into a 3d numpy array; you would usually want either to keep them separate as a list/dict or stack them as a dataframe with an additional row for indexing.

Comment: Where does the error occur?  The `data1D = np.array(data)` step is probably not needed.  `np.stack` works with a list of arrays (in fact if given an array it will just treat it like a list).  `np.stack(data)` should work, if `data` really is a list of matching size arrays.

Comment: I think, before doing what I want I have to convert the dfs to matrices with pd.get_values() and then try to create the matrix based on this. The final goal is to create a matrix as in put for a neural network (feed forward and rnn).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> You need to use

```
 data.reshape((data.shape[0], data.shape[1], 1))
```

> Example

```
from numpy import array
data = [[11, 22],
    [33, 44],
    [55, 66]]
data = array(data)
print(data.shape)
data = data.reshape((data.shape[0], data.shape[1], 1))
print(data.shape)
```

> Running the example first prints the size of each dimension in the 2D array, reshapes the array, then summarizes the shape of the new 3D array.
>
> Result

```
(3,2)
(3,2,1)
```

> Source :https://machinelearningmastery.com/index-slice-reshape-numpy-arrays-machine-learning-python/

Comment: is there any problem

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a 3D Matrix where every subarray is in the new 3D dimension, wouldn't the final shape be `(350,9,5)`? In that case, you can simply use:

```
new_array = np.asarray(data).reshape(350,9,5)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems from your question that getKmers(x, 9) produces a list of 9 length-350 lists, and the `data` input has 5 elements.  You want a (9, 5, 350) array out of this.  This should be achievable with:

`arr = np.swapaxes([getKermers(x, 9) for x in data], 0, 1)`

Note that `swapaxes` is NOT the same as reshaping.  If you were to just do `np.array([getKermers(x, 9) for x in data]).reshape(9, 5, 350)`, you'd end up with the desired output shape but your data would be in the wrong order.